# salesforce translations - referencing quote status picklist in aura component via $Label

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have added custom quote status picklist values and translated them. I can see the german equivalent of these in Translation Workbench > Translate. How can I refer them in the .cmp file? If it is a label, I am referencing as - {!$Label.c.LBL_XXXXX}, how do I reference a picklist value as I don't see them under custom labels? Right now, I reference for a quote as -  {!v.quote.Status}, but obviously will only get the english equivalent. Please advise.

Comment: You need a server-side call. The code in the linked question provides one solution to this problem. Simply call it with the parameters to get the Status field, and it will be translated per the user's language setting.

Comment: Thanks! I followed the solution and was able to get it working on the dev org, but when we package the solution, and try to run this on the packaging org where the package is installed, it doesn't work -                               
String objectName = 'Quote';
String fieldName = 'Status';
for(PicklistEntry pkLstEntry: ((SObject)(Type.forName('Schema.'+objectName).newInstance())).getSObjectType()
    .getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
  
        System.debug('Pklst: '+pkLstEntry.getValue()+' , '+pkLstEntry.getLabel());        
    }